# Generics with structs and fields

Tags: c#, xna

Hello I have a problem with generics, i'am creating a custom vertex structure for my game and i want to be abel to do this with generics so i can change my vertex type quickly.

this is what it looks like right now:

```
public struct ETerrainVertex
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Vector3 Normal;
    public Vector2 TextureCoordinate;

    public static int SizeInBytes = (3 + 3 + 2) * 4;
    public static VertexElement[] VertexElements = new VertexElement[]
    {
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0),
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0)
    };
}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
//I have to add a constraint to the T but an interface wont cut.
//where T : struct, thingThatAddsConstrainsPositionAndNormal
public sealed class EQuadNode<T> : IEclipse where T : struct
{ 
    T foo;
    foo.Position; //dont work
}
```

But since I use fields i cant simply create an interface and add it to the where restrictions as interfaces only can have properties.

So is there any way to do this?

Comment: you cannot do *what* because of using fields? Question is unclear to me as is.

Comment: hi, where is the generics in there (the T)? Maybe you wanted to write public struct ETerrainVertex<T>? I don't understand the comment with the fields and interface - can you try to explain this - maybe with the code you tried?

Comment: what is wrong with: where T : struct?

Comment: the problem is, he wants to create an interface for ETerrainVertex
, but fields are not allowed in interfaces, as he only has fields this would lead to an empty interface (which is not possible)

Comment: exactly edited it abit hope it clarifies.

Comment: why not create a interface with properties? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create in interface for `ETerrainVertex` if you use properties instead of fields:

```
public interface IVertex
{
    public Vector3 Position {get;set;}
 }

public struct ETerrainVertex : IVertex
{
    public Vector3 Position {get;set;}
}
```

Don't worry about the performance impact of using properties, as there is none in this case IIRC.

Comment: Don't need the override keyword, since the base is an interface, not a class.

Comment: Yes, I have done that now and everything seems to work ok, thank you for your time guys.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use **only** `ETerrainVertex` - you should **not** use generics and put the type explicitly. Using generics in such case is just meaningless because you won't be able to use any other type but `ETerrainVertex`.
If you want to use another types - you should use inheritance. And because CLR don't allow you to inherit from structs - you `should` specify an interface and encapsulate your fields into properties in your structure.

And next **important** thing - if you decide to use interface - it's possible that a lot of boxing operations will occur which can hurt performance of your application.

Comment: Yeah i wanted to avoid encapsulateing but i guess i have no choice.
The problem is that the fields go to a directx hsls file and i'am not sure if properties work, becouse there are none in any exemple I've seen.

Comment: @Spinno: Probably minimal overhead, wouldn't be surprised if the JIT optimizes a lot of that away when properties just return backing fields.